# Post-build event command line; how to level up in path and how to handle spaces

Tags: post-build-event, post-build

My goal is to copy a XML file from one project to another project in my solution after a succesful build.

```
copy $(SolutionDir)Xenos.Core.API\XmlDocumentXenosCoreApi.xml $(ProjectDir)App_Data\XmlDocumentXenosCoreApi.xml
```

This would translate in this.

```
copy D:\XENOSTFS2015\Sprint Development\Diversification Sprints\Xenos Main\Xenos.Core.API\XmlDocumentXenosCoreApi.xml D:\XenosTFS2015\Sprint Development\Diversification Sprints\Suite\XenosWebAPI\App_Data\XmlDocumentXenosCoreApi.xml
```

But I want the first argument of copy to be like this, so the solutiondir should go two levels up. A

```
D:\XENOSTFS2015\Sprint Development\Diversification Sprints\Suite\XenosCoreApi\XmlDocumentXenosCoreApi.xml
```

Also I'm worried that the spaces will prevent the copy from executing, how can I solve this?

Thx in advance !!